# Confusing Error Message While Running NPM Install on Cloned Github Repo

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, npm

I am trying to run `npm install` in a git repo (made in JS and TS) I just cloned to work with, and I'm getting a very confusing error message. I tried restarting my command prompt, my device, and deleting/recloning the repo. I see several very confusing things, like it mentioning Python, when there is NO Python in the project.

The error message is below:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\constantinople',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\constantinople'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4082,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\constantinople'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\sails-postgresql\\node_modules\\async',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\sails-postgresql\node_modules\async'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\sails-postgresql\\node_modules\\async'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Binary found at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-115\binding.node
npm ERR! Testing binary
npm ERR! Binary has a problem: Error: \\?\C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-115\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application.
npm ERR! \\?\C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-115\binding.node
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
npm ERR!     at module.exports (C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:13:35)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! Building the binary locally
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python 3 executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python312\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.12.1"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '20.10.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "20.10.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Projects\\Update-Server\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\USERNAME\Projects\Update-Server\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-18T17_29_44_942Z-debug-0.log
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "electron-release-server",
  "private": true,
  "version": "2.1.3",
  "description": "A version server for hosting and serving the your electron desktop app releases.",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/upgrade": "^1.0.9",
    "async": "^3.2.4",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "bower": "^1.8.14",
    "compare-versions": "^4.1.4",
    "consolidate": "^0.16.0",
    "db-migrate": "^0.11.13",
    "db-migrate-pg": "^1.2.2",
    "express-useragent": "^1.0.15",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "grunt": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-pug": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.2.2",
    "grunt-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^3.0.1",
    "include-all": "~4.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "ldapauth-fork": "^5.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-ldapauth": "^3.0.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "rc": "~1.2.8",
    "sails": "^1.5.3",
    "sails-disk": "^2.1.2",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^5.0.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^4.0.2",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.3",
    "sails-pg-session": "^1.0.1",
    "sails-postgresql": "^5.0.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.8",
    "skipper-disk": "^0.5.12",
    "strip-bom": "^4.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "v2land-sails-pg-session": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "inspect": "node --inspect app.js",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "migrate": "db-migrate",
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "eslint": "eslint ./*.js api assets/js config migrations tasks",
    "stylelint": "stylelint assets/styles/*.*"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.16.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^29.0.0"
  }
}
```

And the repository is [here](https://github.com/ArekSredzki/electron-release-server).

Comment: Are you using ubuntu?

Comment: No- Windows 11. Just got the computer (used) from a family member yesterday, actually.

Comment: which repo is it? or is it private? try to remove the folder node_modules and please rename the root folder -> `Update-Server` to something without hypen (avoid hypes pls!!) -> `UpdateServer` ... could be just path issue .. pls provide also package.json content

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: Can you explain why this is a confusing error? node-gyp is a standard utility for building binaries to target specific platforms if they are not already found on your system. Each platform needs tooling to do this (e.g. gcc on linux, Visual Studio on Windows?). Python is also a common component of tooling to build binaries. The error as I read it is "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio...https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows" which seems explicit.

Comment: I just can't seem to find a solution, and I'm following those obvious steps, but it's not doing anything.